# Does this algorithm have a name?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Does this algorithm have a name? I've listed three examples of it below. I'm wanting to document some code that uses this algorithm, and I don't know what to call it. My version is way more complicated but it is fundamentally this.

**Example 1:**

```
var maxValue = Int32.MinValue;
foreach (var value in new [] {2, 3, 4, 4, -3, 1, 7})
{
    if (value > maxValue)
        maxValue = value;
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
var minValue = Int32.MaxValue;
foreach (var value in new [] {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 20, 42})
{
    if (value < maxValue)
        minValue = value;
}
```

**Example 3:**

```
var mostPrimeFactors = 0;
var valueWithMostPrimeFactors = 0
foreach (var value in new [] {2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 60, 360})
{
    var primeFactorCount = GetPrimeFactors(value).Count;
    if (primeFactorCount > mostPrimeFactors)
    {
        mostPrimeFactors = primeFactorCount
        mostPrimeFactors = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you see *algorithm* here?  Seems to be a linear procedure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: Your last example seems buggy. Shouldn't the second line in the `if` be `valueWithMostPrimeFactors = value;`?

Comment: What's the point of finding the min and max values here?

Comment: @Jordan no, he is not. This isn't a programming problem.  I'm voting to close this question as opinion-based.

Comment: And this is a programming question, but you are getting off topic.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms

Comment: @LukeHutton, thank you for moving me to the correct pigeon hole. Do they have a stackexchange site where you can ask which stackexchange site to use for your question? That'd be nice. I've been with stack exchange for almost a decade, and people used to actually answer my questions. Well, carry on with your reputation farming.

Comment: @LukeHutton [stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) - Not sure what you're getting at by pointing out that Software Engineering also has an algorithms tag.

Comment: Consider "sequential minmax search".

Comment: StackOverflow just doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Varying opinions here but was looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521/168927 Thought stackoverflow more about implementation, not design but hey, you got answers here since more people here. p.s. relax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all seem to be examples of linear search. According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search):

> It sequentially checks each element of the list for the target value until a match is found or until all the elements have been searched.

Comment: That doesn't quite match up - OP's algorithm is not looking for a specific value and will never return early.

Comment: @BJMyers - In each case, OP is searching for an extreme value of some sort. As to returning early, note the second part of Wikipedia's definition: _...or until all the elements have been searched_.

Comment: I still disagree.  The Wikipedia article further specifies that linear search *checks each element...until it finds an element that matches the target value.  If the algorithm reaches the end of the list, the search terminates unsuccessfully.*  OP's algorithm does not have a target value to check against, nor does it terminate "unsuccessfully" if all the elements are "searched."

Comment: @BJMyers - Suppose I gave you the following search algorithm: find the largest element of an array by looking at every element in sequence and keeping track of the largest value found so far. I hope you agree that this is a search algorithm. What would you call that algorithm if not _linear search_?

Comment: @BJMyers I think you're reading too much into the Wikipedia article. Linear search just means that you check each element in order. Another [description](http://algorithms.openmymind.net/search/linear.html) might explain it better.

Comment: @TedHopp No actually, my argument is specifically that "finding the largest element" is not a search algorithm.  A search algorithm executes a test against elements that can immediately determine whether or not they match the target value.  Determining the largest element is an aggregation performed over a set of data, rather than a search to find a matching element in that data.  (Although, the colloquial term "search" has found its way into the vocabulary of many such aggregation operations, so we're definitely down to splitting hairs at this point.)

Comment: @BJMyers - Yes, I agree about splitting hairs. I'll just point out that the [Wikipedia article _Search algorithm_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm) defines the term very broadly. Donald Knuth, in his classic _Sorting and Searching_, defined _search_ formally as looking up a value given a key as input, so perhaps he would agree with you that what I described isn't a search algorithm. On the other hand, in the "sorting" part of the book, he describes looking at all elements to find the maximum as "search". In my book, when you're trying to find something, you're searching.